# module in zend framework not loading index controller

Tags: zend-framework

Following Pro Zend Framework techniques, I have created a module named 'Contact' in modules directory. Here's the directory structure.

```
    |_application
     |_Configs
       |_application.ini
     |_controllers
     |_modules
       |_Contact
          |_Controllers
             |_IndexController
          |_models
          |_views
          Bootstrap.php

    Bootstrap.php
```

The Bootstrap file in the application directory has an _initAutoload() function as shown below:

```
    protected function _initAutoLoad(){
    $autoLoader = Zend_Loader_Autoloader::getInstance();
    $autoLoader->registerNamespace('CMS_');
    $resourceLoader = new Zend_Loader_Autoloader_Resource(
    array('basePath' => APPLICATION_PATH , 'namespace' => '' ,
    'resourceTypes' => array('form' => array('path' => 'forms/' , 'namespace' => 'Form_') ,
    'model' => array('path' => 'models/' , 'namespace' => 'Model_'))));

    return $autoLoader;
    }
```

The Bootstrap file in the **modules** is:

```
    class Contact_Bootstrap extends Zend_Application_Module_Bootstrap
    {
    protected function _initAutoLoad(){
    $autoloader=new Zend_Application_Module_Autoloader(array('namespace'=>'Contact_',
    'basePath'=>dirname(__FILE__),));
    return $autoLoader;
    }
    }
```

The application.ini file in the config folder has the following lines for setting up the module 'contact':

```
    resources.frontController.moduleDirectory = APPLICATION_PATH "/modules"
    resources.modules[] = ""
    contact.resources.frontController.defaultControllerName = "index"
```

I have set up an application error controller which has a getmessage() function to display the error. When I try to load, http://localhost/zf_cms/public/contact, it gives an error:

```
    getMessage() : Invalid controller specified (index)
```

The name of the index controller in modules->contact->controller is Contact_IndexController. I also created a view for index controller.

Please help me find the bug and let me know if I missed some info.
Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

rename module and controller directory to  lowercase . And it seems from your post that you are not adding .php extension to your IndexController do that aswell .

Comment: Thank you very much. I just had to rename the module directory to lowercase.